# How to return a list containing the elements which are in both list1 and list2 using MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, search, comparison

I am trying to compare `list1` and `list2` in MATLAB and get a third list `list3` which contains all the elements from `list1` which are also in `list2` (including duplicate entries in `list1`).

For example, `list1` contains the elements

```
AA,AB,AC,AC,AC,CB
```

and `list2` the following ones:

```
BA,BB,AC,BN,MN,CB,CB
```

Therefore, `list3` should contain

```
AC,AC,AC,CB
```

Since `AC` can be found three times in `list1`, it has also to be represented three times in `list3`. `CB` is twice in `list2` but only once in `list1`, so it should be shown only once in `list3`.

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: try `list1(ismember(list1, list2))`.

Comment: @saastn write it up as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ismember`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwinrb_khvnNAhWCbRQKHeUgCpwQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com%2Fhelp%2Fmatlab%2Fref%2Fismember.html&usg=AFQjCNEMg9OE8mDUs0v0WSqUlLvwckaTNw&sig2=qi66XfAlfFgJnXE75dlDAQ&bvm=bv.127178174,d.bGs) for this.

> `tf = ismember(A, S)` returns an array the same size as `A`, containing logical `1` (`true`) where the elements of `A` are in the set `S`, and logical `0` (`false`) elsewhere. In set theory terms, `k` is `1` where `A` ∊ `S`. Inputs `A` and `S` can be numeric or character arrays or cell arrays of strings.

If you define `list1` and `list2` as cell arrays it will become like this:

```
list1 = {'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AC', 'AC', 'CB'}
list2 = {'BA', 'BB', 'AC', 'BN', 'MN', 'CB', 'CB'}
I = ismember(list1, list2) % positions where the elements of list1 are in the set list2
list3 = list1(ismember(list1, list2))
```

it will return:

```
I =     0     0     1     1     1     1
list3 = 'AC'    'AC'    'AC'    'CB'
```

You can also define your lists(sets) as matrices (if all elements in sets have same length). In that case you need to pass another parameter to `ismember`.

> `tf = ismember(A, S, 'rows')`, when `A` and `S` are matrices with the same number of columns, returns a vector containing `1` where the rows of `A` are also rows of `S` and `0` otherwise. You cannot use this syntax if `A` or `S` is a cell array of strings.

```
list1 = ['AA'; 'AB'; 'AC'; 'AC'; 'AC'; 'CB']
list2 = ['BA'; 'BB'; 'AC'; 'BN'; 'MN'; 'CB'; 'CB']
I = ismember(list1, list2, 'rows')
list3 = list1(ismember(list1, list2, 'rows'), :)
```

That returns:

```
I =
0
0
1
1
1
1


list3 =
AC
AC
AC
CB
```